# Embed an R & Python REPL in WPF

Tags: c#, python, wpf, r

Is there a way to embed a R REPL and a Python REPL in a WPF application? I wanted to embed an active REPL that would take input from the keyboard and then after an enter stroke would evaluate the input in the desired language and produce the output from the application inputted.

Thanks!